# C++ using ICU and Nana GUI Library - String conversion?

Tags: c++, encoding, utf-16, icu, nana

I just did some successful tests with ICU in C/C++. I need to parse different CSV files with different encodings (might be UTF-8, UTF-16LE, ), do some modifications on the data and finally output everything as UTF-8 into a file. That's why my choice fell for ICU. Character set detection works pretty well usually, character handling and conversion to UTF-8 too.

Now I wanted to integrate that library part that does CSV loading, manipulation and so on with a GUI library, Nana. Nana seems to use std::string and std::wstring.

As ICU stores all data internally as UTF-16, so either I got UChars or UnicodeStrings when working with ICU. But how could I use either of them with Nana, that doesn't 'integrate' with ICU? Any way to transform UChar arrays to wstring, or a UnicodeString to wstring?

Didn't find any hints in the ICU documentation, so...maybe somebody else already worked on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most nana functions expect `std::string` encoded in UTF-8.

You could use the [ICU functions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/utf-8) that take or return `char *` to do the conversion to UTF-8.

A few of nana functions, like [`widget::caption`](https://github.com/cnjinhao/nana/blob/develop/include/nana/gui/widgets/widget.hpp) have overloads for `std::wstring` expected to be encoded in UTF-16 (in windows) or UTF-32 (in Linux) which could be used to pass to the OS what could be the string with the native character type and encoding.
In case you need conversions nana offers [`nana::charset`](https://github.com/cnjinhao/nana/blob/develop/include/nana/charset.hpp) which can manage (explicitly or implicitly) some of the most frequently needed conversions from/to UTF-8/UTF-16/UTF-32.

If you experiment passing `static_cast<wchar_t *>(some_UChar*)` to nana, please tell us about the result. I can't test.

The nana documentation about Unicode treatment urgently need to be updated (*mea culpa*)

Comment: Hello there! I will test those ICU functions of course. I just found functions from ICU like 'u_strToWCS' which allows to convert the UChar* to a wchar_t *, so I'm pretty sure that this is working.
I will also do some experiments with static_cast<wchar_t *> and let you know what happens. My expectation is that this is going to work well on Windows, but on Unix/Linux platform...

Comment: you may need to add a terminal 0 to your UChar* string ??

Comment: Depends. Usually when working with string manipulation functions in ICU it gets added by the function (like u_sprintf or similar). Otherwise yes, you will have to add it yourself.

Comment: you could use  `#ifdef U_WCHAR_IS_UTF16` from ICU to determine whether this cast would work and use `u_strToWCS()` otherwise. Or just always call `u_strToWCS()` which is what it is for.

Answer (score 0):

According to ICU documentation, a UChar array is an array of 16 bits wide characters... meaning a wchar_t array in common implementations. That means that provided wchar_t is 16 bits wide in your system, you can safely cast the result of the `getTerminatedBuffer()` function to a `const wchar_t *` and either use it directly as a C wide chararcter string, or use it to build a `std::wstring`.

Comment: This is not true w.r.t. strict aliasing, unless you make sure that `UChar` is `wchar_t`.

Comment: If UChar and wchar_t are both integral types of same size they are the same type (only the sign could cause problem)

Comment: That's true in C but not C++.  In C++, `wchar_t` is its own type, not a typedef.

Comment: (Also it's not true in general in C either... `int` and `long` are often the same size but they are never allowed to alias.)

Comment: Well, I guess if it's just a matter of style, I don't care. It seems that wchar_t and UChar have the same implementation, though I read that wchar_t can be quite compiler dependant. That's why I was a bit unsure of what to do. "Yes it works, but does it work on every [Windows] system?"